# Zip Code when converting .xlsx to .csv

Tags: python, csv, xlsx, xlrd, import-from-excel

Excel stores zip codes as floats. When using xlsx.py the following happens

zip[1] = 01234 > 1234.0  (nope)

zip[2] = 12345-6789 > 12345-6789  (perfect)

```
import xlrd
import csv
def csv_from_excel():
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('mydoc.xlsx')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    mycsv = open('output.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(mycsv)

    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        cell = sh.cell(rownum,0)
        wr.writerow([unicode(val).encode('utf8') for val in sh.row_values(rownum)])

    mycsv.close()
```

How can I keep leading zeros, remove the appended .0 and account for "-" in extended zip codes? Converting to integer will remove the leading zero and using csv="QUOTE-ALL" only complicates things further with added characters.

Comment: store them as `'01234`. the `'` forces excel to treat the value as a string, and not apply any numeric formatting rules.

Comment: I want to avoid editing this file if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

To turn 123 into "00123", you can use "{:0>5}".format(zipcode)
This will right-align the data inside a 5-character long string, and use "0" for padding.